# JQuery keyup/down isn't working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```js
$('#user_text').keyup(function(){
 var user_text = $('#user_text').val();
 $('#user_text_feedback').html(user_text);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jquery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="user_text" value="hey"><br />
 <span id="user_text_feedback"></span>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using google chrome as my default browser. I tried to execute the above code but I'm not getting the required output.I also tried using keydown instead of keyup I wasn't getting the proper output

Comment: where is "user_link"?? you should use "user_text"

Comment: oh..my bad ..thanx bud :)

Comment: thanks.. upvote comment if you can :)

Comment: now after edit it start working :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$('#user_link')` to `$('#user_text')`:

```
$('#user_text').keyup(function(){
    var user_text = $('#user_text').val();
    $('#user_text_feedback').html(user_text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Working here you should use `#user_text` :

```js
$('#user_text').keyup(function(){
 var user_text = $('#user_text').val();
 $('#user_text_feedback').html(user_text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jquery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="user_text" value="hey"><br />
 <span id="user_text_feedback"></span>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```